# Deploying with python 3 on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy to heroku and using python 3.  However the heroku build pack defaults to python 2.7.

The build pack read me mentions that a runtime.txt file can be added to change the default runtime.
I'm not clear on the instructions but I've added a runtime.txt file to the root of my project folder with

```
python-3.4.3
```

in it.  After this if I do:

```
heroku create
```

then:

```
git push heroku master
```

This doesn't work and still commences the build python 2.7.
Note I do get a custom build pack detected notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you gave is vague, but if you're following the steps exactly as you say, then you're forgetting to `git add` and `git commit` before pushing to heroku.